# Get solution to overdetermined linear homogeneous system numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-regression

I'm trying to find the solution to **overdetermined linear homogeneous system** (Ax = 0) using numpy in order to get the least linear squares solution for a linear regression.

This is the code I am using to generate the linear regression:

```
N = 100
x_data = np.linspace(0, N-1, N)
m = +5
n = -5
y_model = m*x_data + n
y_noise = y_model + np.random.normal(0, +5, N)
```

I want to recover **m** and **n** from **y_noise**. In other words, I want to resolve the homogeneous system (Ax = 0) where "***x = (m, n)***" and "***A = (x_data | 1 | -y_noise)***". So I convert non-homogeneous (Ax = y) into homogeneous (Ax = 0) using this code:

```
A = np.array(np.vstack((x_data, np.ones(N), -y_noise)).T)
```

I know I could resolve non-homogeneous system using ***np.linalg.lstsq((x_data | 1), y_noise))*** but I want to get the solution for homogeneous system. I am finding a problem with this function as it only returns the **trivial solution** (x = 0):

```
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, np.zeros(N))[0] => array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I was thinking about using **eigenvectors** to get the solution but it seems not to work:

```
A_T_A = np.dot(A.T, A)
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eig(A_T_A)
# eigenvectors
[[ -2.03500000e-01   4.89890000e+00   5.31170000e+00]
 [ -3.10000000e-03   1.02230000e+00  -2.64330000e+01]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
# eigenvectors normalized
[[ -0.98365497700  -4.744666220   1.0]  # (m1, n1, 1)
 [  0.00304878118   0.210130914   1.0]  # (m2, n2, 1)
 [  25.7752417000  -5.132910010   1.0]] # (m3, n3, 1)
```

Which none of them fits model parameters (m=+5, n=-5)

How can I find (m, n) correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Singular value decomposition will give you the best solution you can get.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820841/methods-for-solving-ax-0

Comment: The approach you consider to find the (least squares) solution is wrong. Matrix `A` of the homogeneous system is full (column) rank with probability one, therefore, the only solution is the trivial, all-zeros solution, which, `lstsq` correctly returns.

Comment: A person who analyzed solid mechanics using finite elements for a living would say that you have an infinite number of rigid body solutions that are all equally viable.  You need to get a solution with the rigid body modes removed.

Comment: @Stelios So, is there no way to get solution using homogeneous system? Do I have to use non-homogeneous system or can I rewrite A in a different way to satisfy homogeneous solution?

Comment: @sevolo The least squares solution you are seeking is by definition the value of `x` that minimizes `norm(A*x-y)`. If you do not want to find `x` the "obvious way", you should take care that the different problem formulation you will be considering gives the same answer. I do not have any hints for this. Actually, I do not see the point in a "homogeneous solution" formulation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found how to fix it, the problem is how I was interpreting the output of **np.linalg.eig** function, but the approach using eigenvectors is right. In spite of that, **@Stelios** is in the right when he says that the function **np.linalg.lstsq** returns the trivial solution (x = 0) because matrix A is full column rank.

I was assuming the output of **np.linalg.eig** was:

```
[[m1 n1  1]
 [m2 n2  1]
 [m3 n3  1]]
```

But it is not, the correct format is:

```
[[m1 m2 m3]
 [n1 n2 n3]
 [ 1  1  1]]
```

So if we want to get the solution which better fits model paramaters (m, n), we have to choose the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue and normalize it:

```
A_T_A = np.dot(A_homo.T, A_homo)
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eig(A_T_A)  
# eigenvectors
[[  1.96409304e-01   9.48763118e-01  -2.47531678e-01]
 [  2.94608003e-04   2.52391765e-01   9.67625088e-01]
 [ -9.80521952e-01   1.90123494e-01  -4.92925776e-02]]
# MIN eigenvector
eigen_vector_min = eigen_vectors[:, np.argmin(eigen_values)]
[-0.24753168  0.96762509 -0.04929258]
# MIN eigenvector normalized
[  5.02168258 -19.63023915   1.        ]   # [m, n, 1]
```

Finally we get that **m = 5.02** and **n = -19,6** which is a pretty good approximation.