# Determining the corresponding columns in V of singular values in Numpy SVD

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, least-squares, svd

I'm trying to use SVD to estimate the solution for non-square matrix of linear equations. 
My matrix is of the `8 x 6` shape.

I calculated the following parameters using:

```
U, sigma, VT = np.linalg.svd(mat)
```

Now, I am suggested to take a column from V with the smallest the corresponding value in S, and that should be the solution to my 6 parameters that I'm trying to determine with 8 equations.

Can somebody please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh! sorry guys, Thank you for your time. Actually I sorted out the problem with the slightly different answer here about the [least square estimation of over-determined condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451333/get-solution-to-overdetermined-linear-homogeneous-system-numpy).

And this seems to do, I simply had to do:

```
sol_min = VT[:, np.argmin(sigma)]
```